# Azure Functions: How do I control development/production/staging app settings?

Tags: json, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, devops

I've just started experimenting with Azure functions and I'm trying to understand how to control the app settings depending on environment.

In dotnet core you could have appsettings.json, appsettings.development.json etc. And as you moved between different environments the config would change.

However from looking at Azure function documentation all I can find is that you can set up config in the azure portal but I can't see anything about setting up config in the solution?

So what is the best way to manage build environment?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion, is using a proper build and release system, like [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/).

What I've done in one of my solutions is creating an ARM template of my Function App and deploy this using a release pipeline with VSTS RM.

This way you can just add a value to the `template.json`, like the one from below.

```
"appSettings": [
    // other entries
    {
        "name": "MyValue",
        "value": "[parameters('myValue')]"
    }
```

You will need another file, called `parameters.json` which will hold the values. This file looks like so (at the moment).

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {},
        "storageName": {},
        "location": {},
        "subscriptionId": {}
    }
}
```

Back in VSTS you can just change/override the values of these parameters in the portal.
[image: override parameters]

By using such a workflow you will get a professional CI/CD implementation where no one has to bother themselves with the actual secrets. They are only known to the system administrators.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've done some further reading in search of answers and it seems that although using a dotnet core style appsettings is on the list of jobs for microsoft using ARM was their answer to the problem.

Looks like a good DevOps approach too!

Comment: In my case, I have Azure Functions which have around 50+ application settings and there are slots involved (production/staging slots). It's tedious to define these 50+ settings in the template.json twice. I wish I could pass in an array of objects from the parameters.json and simply reference that in the template.json.